# Trying to use replace ((value),"\W","") on oracle xquery

Tags: oracle, xquery

Could someone explain why does replace \w (word-character) work and \W (non-word-character) does not .
How to solve it.

```
create table test (xmldata) as
select xmltype('<workbook>
 <worksheet sheetName="asd-kasd" sheetId="1"/>
</workbook>') 
from dual;

update test
set XMLDATA=
           xmlquery(
             'copy $d := .
             modify (
                for $i in $d/workbook/worksheet/@sheetName
                return replace value of node $i with concat("1.\w:",replace(string($i/../@sheetName),"\w",""),"2. \W:",replace($i/../@sheetName,"\W",""))
            )
              return $d'
            passing test.XMLDATA
            returning content
         );

ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation: 
XVM-01126: [FORX0003] Regular expression matches zero-length string
```

fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ede05cbbe55f36074c36457e9491fc11

Error:

```
ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation: 
XVM-01126: [FORX0003] Regular expression matches zero-length string
```

after using \W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Oracle's implementation of the standard XQuery `fn:replace()` function. Using the metacharacter `\W` causes `fn:replace` to fail, on every string that I tested. I'd suggest [opening a Service Request with Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Support%20Tools/1321379_1.html) to report it.

You can verify using an non-Oracle XQuery tester (e.g. [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery)) that `replace()` should handle `\W` just fine.

Oddly, the deprecated [ora:replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5996) function does work correctly. So you could use that as a workaround until Oracle patches the bug. But note that this function is non-standard - for example, it supports POSIX-style metacharacters (e.g. `[[:alnum:]]`) which the XQuery standard does not.

I simplified your query to give a more minimal verifiable example, and could reproduce the issue on Oracle 12.2.0.1. Comment out the "fn" column to get correct results.

```
select 
    regexp_replace('asd-kasd','\W','') as rr, -- normal regexp engine works fine
    -- \W fails, with any string
    xmlquery('fn:replace("asd-kasd","\W","")' returning content) as fn,
    -- deprecated ora:replace works fine
    xmlquery('ora:replace("asd-kasd","\W","")' returning content) as ora
from dual
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2af82cbb9d6db4777782c5911efd42f7)

Comment: The metacharacter `\W` is defined in the XQuery regex dialect (though it might not have exactly the same meaning as in Perl). The construct `[^[:alnum:]_]` is not supported in this regex dialect, unless I have misunderstood the notation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for clarifying! I'll edit to remove that, to make it more clear.